# What happened to my strings in both strcpy() and custom function?

Tags: c, char, copy, c-strings, strcpy

I have been doing well with the string functions I've been making recently. So then, I made my 3rd string function that is basically like `strcpy()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *copy_str(const char *str);

int main() {
    char name[256];
    printf("What's your name? "); scanf("%255s", name);
    char result[256] = copy_str(name);
    printf("Hello, %s.\n", result);
}

const char *copy_str(const char *str) {
    return str;
}
```

I didn't try using the `strcpy()` function itself in the function I made, because I'm not really familiar with it. Then I got an error:

```
copy_str.c:9:10: error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal
    char result[256] = copy_str(name);
         ^
```

I fixed it this way:

```
int main() {
    char name[256];
    printf("What's your name? "); scanf("%255s", name);
    char result[256];
    strcpy(name, result);
    printf("Hello, %s.\n", result);
}
```

But then the output went like this:

```
What's your name? builderman
Hello, .
```

No string for some reason. Even if you typed in a different string, it would be the same result.

Q: **Why did `strcpy()` ruin my string? What ways can I improve my function?**

Comment: [man strcpy](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html): `char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);` Note the order of the args.

Comment: `char result[256] = copy_str(name);` You can't assign a pointer to an array.  You want to say this,  `const char* result = copy_str(name);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions in parts.

1. copy_str.c:9:10: error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal

   char result[256] = copy_str(name);

the meaning of this error is that in C syntax you cannot initialize an array the way that you did.
you can only initialize an array of chars with either a literal like so:

```
char name[] = "Hello";
```

or an initialization list like so:

```
char name[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
```

you can't initialize an array with a pointer to a char (which is the return value of your function)

2. strcpy doesn't magically copy an entire string to another one, it iterates over the string until it finds a NULL terminator '\0'
   so a simple implementation of strcpy can be:

   ```
   char *StrCpy(char *dest, const char *src)
   {
    char *returned_str = dest;

    while (*src != '\0')
    {
       *dest = *src;
       src++;
       dest++;
    }
    *dest = '\0';

    return returned_str;
   }
   ```

so strcpy iterates over the strings and copies each character from src to dest.
a problem may arise when sending an array of characters that doesn't have a null terminator at the end of the array, which is how a string should be terminated in C.

Answer (score 2):

The function `strcpy` has the following declaration

```
char *strcpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);
```

That is the first parameter defines the array where the string pointed to by the second parameter is copied.

However in your program

```
int main() {
    char name[256];
    printf("What's your name? "); scanf("%255s", name);
    char result[256];
    strcpy(name, result);
    printf("Hello, %s.\n", result);
}
```

you are copying the non-initialized character array `result` into the array `name`.

You have to write

```
    strcpy( result, name );
```

instead of

```
    strcpy(name, result);
```

As for the first program then the function `copy_str` is redundant. You could just write

```
char result[256] = name;
```

However the initializer has the type `char *` due to the implicit conversion of an array to pointer to its first element. So such initialization of an array is incorrect.  You may initialize a character array with a string literal like

```
char s[] = "Hello";
```

But you may not use a character pointer to initialize a character array like

```
char t[] = "Hello";
char s[] = t;
```

Your function `copy_str` could look the following way

```
char * copy_str( char *dsn, const char *src )
{
    for ( char *p = dsn; ( *p++ = *src++ ); );

    return dsn;
}
```